# Creating remote background process in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a bat script which will run indefinitely on a remote host. At the moment, I am ussing

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {  Start-Job -ScriptBlock {  c:\prog.bat }}
```

Is this the correct way to create a remote background process?

Comment: probably yes. I think this should belong to the codereview subsite?

Comment: That will work but will not persist across reboots.  You'd be better off adding the script to the startup items if it needs to always start with the server.  if you also need automated recovery you should refactor it as a service.  and @MartinBrandl is probably correct that this belongs on codereview rather than SO

Comment: Took your advise and made a service out of it. Works like a charm!